# How to add styles in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

Hi I am developing web application in Angular 2. I have one drop-down control. In java script it is working fine. I am trying to rewrite it in Angular 2. Below is my html code.

```
<div class="btn-group" (click)="toggleDropdown()">
          <button class="btn-toggle" style="width:151px;" type="button" >Select USer Role</button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="width:100%;">
                      <li *ngFor="let userrole of userroles; let i = index" [value]="userrole.userroleid">
                          <div style="margin-left:3px">
                               <label style="margin-left:2px; margin-right:30px;" class="checkbox-inline" for="inlineCheckbox17"> {{userrole.username}}</label>
                           </div>
                       </li>
                  </ul>
</div>
```

On clicking of btn-group I am trying to add class to the dropdown-menu as below in java script.

```
 $(".btn-toggle").on("click", function () {
     $('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('open');
```

I tried as below. I added click event (click)="toggleDropdown()". In TS file i added

```
toggleDropdown() {
        this._showStyle = true;
  }
```

Then i added below code in html.

```
[ngClass]="{'open': _showStyle }"
```

This works fine. I am struggling to remove styles as I write below code in Javascript.

```
  $(".dropdown-menu li").on("click", function () {

                $('.btn-toggle').text($(this).text());
                $('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('open');
            });
```

I am trying to write above statement in Angular 2. Can someone help me to make this work? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried? Can you share your Angular code?

Comment: Please share you angular code, it will be more helpful to understand. and have a look at this link (https://plnkr.co/edit/fof4c6PBadEfZFnaWT2G?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks. I updated my code

Answer (score 0):

You can create a boolean. For example, `let isDropDownOpen = false;`

And the function would then be:

```
toggleDropdown() {
   return !this.isDropDownOpen;
}
```

And then in the html, you can do the following:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="width:100%;" [ngClass]="{'open': isDropDownOpen}">
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. Adding class works fine. I am looking for    $('.btn-toggle').text($(this).text()); equivalent of javascript.

Comment: That's not what you had before editing your question. Your question was about adding the class.

Comment: Anyway, you can use angular.io/api/core/ViewChild to access the btn-toggle element, and then you can use basic javascript operations to assign the text. Or you can use a directive to access the elementRef angular.io/api/core/ElementRef –